TurtleBot3 Laser Scanner Issue
I am trying to run turtlebot3 simulation and visualize it with RViz however the LaserScan module is not working properly. I am getting a transform error that says
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
For frame [base_scan]: Frame [base_scan] does not exist


I tried changing reference frames but that did not fix it.
My tf tree looks like the following: 
I am using ubuntu 20.04 and using the turtlebot3 files. I am trying to open the included RViz file.

Your transform frame tree should contain many more frames. Please edit your question and provide a url for the tutorial you are following. Also tell us what Operating System you are using.

@Mike973 I just edited. Sorry for the late response.

Seems like the robot_state_publisher is not running, hence the tf tree looks bare. Try launching turtlebot3_remote right after launching the gazebo world:
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=${TB3_MODEL}    # change to right model if not defined in env
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch

That said, it would help if the tutorial link or what commands were ran before you encountered this isse.

https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/ I was following this link

Looks like what you are missing is indeed roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch

You really need to follow a tutorial to successfully get the turtlebot3 simulation to work: you have to set environment variables and run multiple launch files, so you are unlikely to guess how to do that on your own.
You can visit the http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot3_simulations page, scroll down to "ROBOTIS e-Manual for TurtleBot3", then follow the instructions.

I have been following it word by word, but can't make it work, that was why I created this post. The only thing I did not try was to delete Ubuntu and start over.
